# High RX packet error count with modem - how to analyze?

Tags: debian, networking, embedded, modem, mobile

I'm testing a CDMA modem on my Debian embedded Linux system.  I'm doing some wgets of large files and am seeing the connection drop now and then.  Looking at the `ifconfig` output for the PPP interface I see the count for errors seems to be pretty high (353 errors). Is there any easy way of determining what those errors actually are?

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:166.248.251.38  P-t-P:66.174.217.80  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6490 errors:353 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5901 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:7712851 (7.3 MiB)  TX bytes:568635 (555.3 KiB)
```

Comment: Before starting down the neverending road to find an abstruse reason, check the easy things first: are the cables OK, is there noise in the telephone line (try somewhere else), does the cable go near electric power lines, fluorescent lights nearby (they generate a huge amount of electomagnetic noise), ...

Comment: It might be revelant to tell what board, modem, and exact software versions are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use Wireshark to determine why these packets are being retransmitted. Excerpted from this thread in the Wireshark forum, titled: [Wireshark-users: Re: [Wireshark-users] tcp errors detection](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201004/msg00202.html).

*excerpt #1*

> On Sun, Apr 18, 2010 at 4:17 PM, Victor lyamtsev wrote:
>
> > Hi,
> >
> > how can i locate retransmission error for TCP sequence in wireshark
> >     capture ?
> >     Should I look for ACK with repeated sequence number ?
> >     For example:
> >
> > [ACK] Seq = 1355 Ack = 13409 ...
> >     [ACK] Seq = 1355 Ack = 13500
> >
> > How can i detect checksum errors from the capture ?
> >
> > Thanks,
> >     -vvv

*excerpt #2*

```
Also just go to the menu item Analyze>Expert Info.  Click on a, for
example, Retransmission row inside the Expert Infos box and it will
take you to the exact location within the pcap.

On 4/18/10, Abhik Sarkar <sarkar.abhik@xxxxxxxxx> wrote:
> Hi Victor,
>
> Have a look at this page: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html
>
> You can use display filter on the following fields:
> tcp.analysis.retransmission
> tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission
> tcp.checksum_bad
>
> For TCP checksums, please also refer to this page:
> http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Checksum_Verification
> For retransmissions, also refer to this page:
> http://wiki.wireshark.org/PacketLoss
>
> HTH
> Abhik.
>
> On Sun, Apr 18, 2010 at 4:17 PM, Victor lyamtsev <vlyamtsev@xxxxxxxxx>wrote:
>
>> Hi,
>>
>>  how can i locate retransmission error for TCP sequence in wireshark
>> capture ?
>> Should I look for ACK with repeated sequence number ?
>> For example:
>>
>> [ACK] Seq = 1355 Ack = 13409 ...
>> [ACK] Seq = 1355 Ack = 13500
>>
>> How can i detect checksum errors from the capture ?
>>
>> Thanks,
>> -vvv
```

The key resources from that thread:

- [TCP checksums](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Checksum_Verification)
- [retransmissions](http://wiki.wireshark.org/PacketLoss)

You'll want to go under "Expert Info" under the Analyze pulldown, from there if you're capturing packets, you should see several re-transmissions when that'll correlate to your errors.